# Changing screen tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to create a tkinter app that let the user choose between various button at first. Then, when one of these button is clicked, it erases everything on the screen and shows new text but i didn't manage to figure out how to to it. I've tried the frame.pack_forget() but only work one time, if you click on another button it doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
#from class_Carre import Carre
#from class_Cercle import Cercle
#from class_Rectangle import Rectangle

# Initialisation de base
fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.title("Application d'aide en géométrie")
fenetre.geometry("700x720")
fenetre.iconbitmap("logo.ico")
fenetre.config(background = "#03EFFA")
global frame
frame = Frame(fenetre, bg="#03EFFA")

text1 = Label(frame, text="Bienvenue sur ce module d'aide en géométrie !", font=("Courrier", 20), bg="#03EFFA", fg="white")
text2 = Label(frame, text="À l'aide du menu de séléction, vous pourrez accèder à différentes fonctions vous \n permettant de calculer aire et périmètre de différentes figures géométriques.", font=("Courrier", 13), bg="#03EFFA", fg="white")
text3 = Label(frame, text="Toutes les mesures demandées devront être converties en centimètre, ce dernier \n étant l'unité utilisé pour les réponses.", font=("Courrier", 13), bg="#03EFFA", fg="red")
text1.pack()
text2.pack()
text3.pack()
frame.pack(expand=YES)

def carr():
    frame = Frame(fenetre, bg="#03EFFA")
    width = 350
    height = 299
    image = PhotoImage(file="carre.png")
    canvas = Canvas(frame, width=width, height=height, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.create_image(width/2, height/2, image=image, anchor=CENTER)
    canvas.pack()
    frame = Frame(fenetre, bg="#03EFFA")
    #text1 = Label(frame, text="Bienvenue sur ce module d'aide en géométrie !", font=("Courrier", 20), bg="#03EFFA", fg="white")
    #text1.pack()
    frame.pack(expand=YES)

def cerc():
    frame = Frame(fenetre, bg="#03EFFA")
    text1 = Label(frame, text="Bienvenue sur ce module d'aide en géométrie !", font=("Courrier", 20), bg="#03EFFA", fg="white")
    text1.pack()
    frame.pack(expand=YES)

def rect():
    frame = Frame(fenetre, bg="#03EFFA")
    text1 = Label(frame, text="Bienvenue sur ce module d'aide en géométrie !", font=("Courrier", 20), bg="#03EFFA", fg="white")
    text1.pack()
    frame.pack(expand=YES)

def tria():
    frame = Frame(fenetre, bg="#03EFFA")
    text1 = Label(frame, text="Bienvenue sur ce module d'aide en géométrie !", font=("Courrier", 20), bg="#03EFFA", fg="white")
    text1.pack()
    frame.pack(expand=YES)


def quitter():
    msg = messagebox.askquestion ("Sortir du module","Voulez-vous vraiment quitter ?", icon = "error")
    if msg == "yes":
       fenetre.destroy()

# Création barre de menu
menu_bar = Menu(fenetre)
file_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff = 0)
file_menu.add_command(label="Carré", command=lambda:[frame.pack_forget(),carr()])
file_menu.add_command(label="Cercle", command=lambda:[frame.pack_forget(),cerc()])
file_menu.add_command(label="Rectangle", command=lambda:[frame.pack_forget(),rect()])
file_menu.add_command(label="Triangle rectangle", command=lambda:[frame.pack_forget(),tria()])
file_menu.add_command(label="Quitter", command=quitter)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Séléction", menu=file_menu)
fenetre.config(menu=menu_bar)

# Affichage fenetre
fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are using globalization wrong. You have to use the global keyword in the functions, not in the global scope. Globalization is not recommended for apps. Instead use class and objects (OOP) to make your program easier to operate and add changes. Also, you are giveng the same name 'frame' to all of your frames and the inetrpreter gets confused about which variable you are talking about.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Im not sure this is what you are looking for but: As far as I understand the issue you describe in your question you have several buttons to pick from and once one is clicked the screen is cleared and you "open a new screen" or whatever you want to call it. In which case you could just create different Frames, e.g. just create a "home_frame = Frame(...)" or whatever and put your buttons with all the options in them and maybe write a function to like "place all the buttons or whatever". Then just do Frame.destroy and all buttons will disappear. Do that for all your "screens" and youre good...